# When does the constant term in the following expansion is nonzero?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials

**Dyson's Theorem**

The constant term in the expansion of
$$\prod_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n}\left(1-\frac{x_i}{x_j}\right)^{a_i}$$
is the multinomial coefficient
$$\frac{(a_1+\cdots+a_n)!}{a_1!\cdots a_n!},$$
where $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are nonnegative integers.

My question is for general
$$F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\prod_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n}\left(1-\frac{x_i}{x_j}\right)^{a_{ij}}$$
where $a_{ij}$ are nonnegative integers, are there any results or theories about when the constant term in the expansion of $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is nonzero?

Comment: There are numerous papers on constant terms of such products, but of course no general full answer.

Comment: Hello, Fedor Petrov, would you please tell me how to search the papers on constant terms of such products?

Comment: In this paper of G. Károlyi, Z. Nagy, V. Volkov and myself a general technology is presented, it also contains a survey and bibliography

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870815000778

Comment: Fedor Petrov, thank you for your help!